# HEIC photos cannot be viewed in root account

Tags: preview, quicklook, heic

When I'm logged in as root, quicklook and Preview just shows a white picture whenever I preview/open a HEIC photo. Preview also fails to output photos in HEIC; I ended up just having a white photo. However, everything works fine in other user. What can I do to troubleshoot this problem? Here is a video demonstrating the problem: [link](https://scls-my.sharepoint.cn/:v:/g/personal/joyjin_scls-sh_org/EVU-eSl7SHtCqTlTSkeXpQQBvdKF5ovbZeoqso7TM0hvIg?e=gxyFkb).

This is what I mean by a white photo
[image]
[image]

Below is the output of qlmanage -d 4 -p public.heif:

root account

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# 
qlmanage -d 4 -p /Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic 
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    /Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for com.apple.webarchive
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for public.html
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for public.xhtml
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for public.svg-image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.finder.textclipping
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.finder.pictclipping
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.pict
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.internet-location
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Package.qlgenerator> for com.apple.package
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator> for public.image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/SceneKit.qlgenerator> for public.3d-content
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for public.plain-text
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for public.rtf
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for com.apple.rtfd
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for org.oasis-open.opendocument.text
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for com.apple.property-list
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for public.xml
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Font.qlgenerator> for public.font
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator PDF.qlgenerator> for com.adobe.pdf
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Audio.qlgenerator> for public.audio
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator StandardBundles.qlgenerator> for com.apple.application
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator StandardBundles.qlgenerator> for com.apple.systempreference.prefpane
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iBooks.qlgenerator> for org.idpf.epub-folder
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iBooks.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ibooks-folder
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iBooks.qlgenerator> for org.idpf.epub-container
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator LivePhoto.qlgenerator> for com.apple.private.live-photo-bundle
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for public.x509-certificate
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for public.x509-printable-encoded-archive
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for com.rsa.pkcs-12
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for com.apple.keychain
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iChat.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ichat.ichat
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iChat.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ichat.transcript
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Movie.qlgenerator> for public.movie
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Bookmark.qlgenerator> for com.apple.safari.bookmark
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Bookmark.qlgenerator> for com.apple.safari.history
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.bookmark
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.bookmark.todo
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.ics
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.ics.event
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.ics.todo
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Mail.qlgenerator> for com.apple.mail.email
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Mail.qlgenerator> for com.apple.mail.emlx
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator EPS.qlgenerator> for com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator EPS.qlgenerator> for com.adobe.illustrator.ai-image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.word.doc
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.word.dot
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.word.stationery
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.excel.xls
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.excel.xlt
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.powerpoint.pot
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.powerpoint.pps
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.template.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.template.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.template.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.slideshow
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.slideshow.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for public.comma-separated-values-text
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Icon.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iconset
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Contact.qlgenerator> for public.vcard
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Contact.qlgenerator> for com.apple.addressbook.person
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Contact.qlgenerator> for com.apple.addressbook.group
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator LocPDF.qlgenerator> for com.apple.localized-pdf-bundle
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.sffnumbers
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers-tef
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.sfftemplate
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.pages
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.pages-tef
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.sfftemplate
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.key
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.keynote.key
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.sffkey
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.key-tef
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.sffkth
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.kth
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/QuickNFO.qlgenerator> for org.planbnet.nfo
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iBooksAuthor.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ibooksauthor.book
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Finale.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/Finale.qlgenerator> for com.makemusic.musx
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Finale.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/Finale.qlgenerator> for com.makemusic.mus
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Sibelius.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/SibeliusScore.qlgenerator> for com.sibelius.score
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/GarageBandQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.garageband.project
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/GarageBandQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.garageband.template.magic
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/GarageBandQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.garageband.template.magicmentor
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LogicXQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.logicx.project
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.simulink-model-slx
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-app
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-app-install
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-toolbox
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.simulink-template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-data-export
[DEBUG] file:///Applications/Logic%20Pro%20X.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LogicXQLGenerator.qlgenerator/ is older than <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LogicXQLGenerator.qlgenerator>. Ignoring
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DVTProvisioningProfileQuicklookGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.mobileprovision
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DVTProvisioningProfileQuicklookGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.provisionprofile
[DEBUG] Preview test for file:///Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic. Content type UTI: public.heic
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsQL.qlgenerator> for com.parallels.vm.vmpackage
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsQL.qlgenerator> for com.parallels.vm.vmpackage.compressed
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsQL.qlgenerator> for com.vmware.foreign.pvm
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ExeQL.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.windows-executable
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Toolbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsToolboxQuickLookPlugin.qlgenerator> for com.apple.application-bundle
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Toolbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsToolboxQuickLookPlugin.qlgenerator> for com.apple.application
[DEBUG] Previewing file:///Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic. Content type UTI: public.heic. Generator used: <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator>
[DEBUG] Loading <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator>
[DEBUG] Previewing file:///Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic finished
                figPhotoContainer = dict(
                    ApplyTransform = false
                    MaxPixelSize = 1924
                    OutputPixelFormat = 1111970369
                    TiledDownsampling = 1
                )
2020-08-19 17:18:24.219 qlmanage[72790:7314464] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x8303, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2020-08-19 17:18:24.280 qlmanage[72790:7314464] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x13d1f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

This is from an admin account:

```
Last login: Wed Aug 19 17:18:27 on ttys002
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
tmp@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root> 
qlmanage -d 4 -p /Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic 
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    /Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for com.apple.webarchive
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for public.html
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for public.xhtml
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Web.qlgenerator> for public.svg-image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.finder.textclipping
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.finder.pictclipping
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.pict
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Clippings.qlgenerator> for com.apple.internet-location
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Package.qlgenerator> for com.apple.package
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator> for public.image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/SceneKit.qlgenerator> for public.3d-content
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for public.plain-text
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for public.rtf
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for com.apple.rtfd
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for org.oasis-open.opendocument.text
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for com.apple.property-list
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator> for public.xml
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Font.qlgenerator> for public.font
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator PDF.qlgenerator> for com.adobe.pdf
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Audio.qlgenerator> for public.audio
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator StandardBundles.qlgenerator> for com.apple.application
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator StandardBundles.qlgenerator> for com.apple.systempreference.prefpane
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iBooks.qlgenerator> for org.idpf.epub-folder
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iBooks.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ibooks-folder
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iBooks.qlgenerator> for org.idpf.epub-container
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator LivePhoto.qlgenerator> for com.apple.private.live-photo-bundle
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for public.x509-certificate
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for public.x509-printable-encoded-archive
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for com.rsa.pkcs-12
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Security.qlgenerator> for com.apple.keychain
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iChat.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ichat.ichat
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/iChat.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ichat.transcript
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Movie.qlgenerator> for public.movie
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Bookmark.qlgenerator> for com.apple.safari.bookmark
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Bookmark.qlgenerator> for com.apple.safari.history
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.bookmark
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.bookmark.todo
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.ics
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.ics.event
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator iCal.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ical.ics.todo
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Mail.qlgenerator> for com.apple.mail.email
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Mail.qlgenerator> for com.apple.mail.emlx
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator EPS.qlgenerator> for com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator EPS.qlgenerator> for com.adobe.illustrator.ai-image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.word.doc
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.word.dot
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.word.stationery
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.excel.xls
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.excel.xlt
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.powerpoint.pot
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.powerpoint.pps
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.template.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.template.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.template.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.slideshow
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for org.openxmlformats.presentationml.slideshow.macroenabled
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator> for public.comma-separated-values-text
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Icon.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iconset
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Contact.qlgenerator> for public.vcard
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Contact.qlgenerator> for com.apple.addressbook.person
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Contact.qlgenerator> for com.apple.addressbook.group
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator LocPDF.qlgenerator> for com.apple.localized-pdf-bundle
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.sffnumbers
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers-tef
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.sfftemplate
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.numbers.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.pages
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.pages-tef
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.sfftemplate
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.pages.template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.key
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.keynote.key
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.sffkey
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.key-tef
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.sffkth
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator> for com.apple.iwork.keynote.kth
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/QuickNFO.qlgenerator> for org.planbnet.nfo
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Library/QuickLook/iBooksAuthor.qlgenerator> for com.apple.ibooksauthor.book
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Toolbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsToolboxQuickLookPlugin.qlgenerator> for com.apple.application-bundle
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Toolbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsToolboxQuickLookPlugin.qlgenerator> for com.apple.application
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsQL.qlgenerator> for com.parallels.vm.vmpackage
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsQL.qlgenerator> for com.parallels.vm.vmpackage.compressed
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ParallelsQL.qlgenerator> for com.vmware.foreign.pvm
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ExeQL.qlgenerator> for com.microsoft.windows-executable
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DVTProvisioningProfileQuicklookGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.mobileprovision
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DVTProvisioningProfileQuicklookGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.provisionprofile
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Finale.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/Finale.qlgenerator> for com.makemusic.musx
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Finale.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/Finale.qlgenerator> for com.makemusic.mus
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Sibelius.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/SibeliusScore.qlgenerator> for com.sibelius.score
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/GarageBandQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.garageband.project
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/GarageBandQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.garageband.template.magic
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/GarageBandQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.garageband.template.magicmentor
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LogicXQLGenerator.qlgenerator> for com.apple.logicx.project
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.simulink-model-slx
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-app
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-app-install
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-toolbox
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.simulink-template
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Polyspace/R2019b.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/quickLookSLX.qlgenerator> for com.mathworks.matlab-data-export
[DEBUG] file:///Applications/Logic%20Pro%20X.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LogicXQLGenerator.qlgenerator/ is older than <QLGenerator /Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LogicXQLGenerator.qlgenerator>. Ignoring
[DEBUG] Preview test for file:///Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic. Content type UTI: public.heic
[DEBUG] Previewing file:///Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic. Content type UTI: public.heic. Generator used: <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator>
[DEBUG] Loading <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator>
[DEBUG] Previewing file:///Users/tmp/Desktop/public.heic finished
2020-08-19 17:32:12.639 qlmanage[73131:7327456] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xaa03, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2020-08-19 17:32:12.672 qlmanage[73131:7327456] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x13e1f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using root on a Mac?

Comment: It has to do with the default permission of root account that can read+write everywhere. I don't want to do a ```chown -R account /``` and then a ```chown -R +rw account /``` because it might break things.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to be using root on a Mac. It's not even enabled by default, as you can achieve the same using sudo.

Comment: sudo works for CLI programs, but it doesn't work perfectly with GUI apps like Finder. It's not that I can't do the same thing with an admin account, it's just much quicker if I can do what I need to do without having to open any panel or authenticating. I know the risk, and I can accept the risk because there is one time where all my files are deleted partially because of a system bug (and partially because I'm using the root account), but that does not have terrible consequences.