# Simulate user login using command-line utilities

Tags: macos, command-line, login, window-manager, ui

Sometimes, I need to create a login session (create windowserver instance, run login items / launchagents) of an admin user, because a lot of software cannot be run under root (but can be run as another user using `sudo -u <admin user> <path to app executable>` (which requires a windowserver instance of that user or else it will hang every few seconds)), and I don't want to spend a minute logging into another user, waiting for everything to load, and then log back to root. How would I simulate a real user login in command-line?

Comment: You should never need to run anything as root. To quickly switch to a pure admin account I usually use Fast User Switching (without logging out).

Comment: Most applications actually ask for permission if they need additional privileges and are run from a standard account. Is there a typical use case which isn‘t covered by this?

Comment: JoyJin: Just curious, what *"software cannot be run under root*"?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Most of Rogue Amoeba's application (`sudo -u` works), OneDrive (`sudo -u` don't work so a login is required), Microsoft OneNote and Outlook (`sudo -u` don't work), opening online documents and accessing recently opened documents for Microsoft Word/Excel/PowerPoint (`sudo -u` don't work, partially works if app sandboxing is turned off), App Store (network failure if sandbox is not switched off), iBooks (just won't work).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Also touch bar (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401630/touchbar-does-not-work-in-root-account), heif (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399610/heic-photos-cannot-be-viewed-in-root-account).

Comment: @nohillside I know. But I often modify system files (`/Library`, `/etc`, etc.), system settings (`defaults`, `launchctl`, etc.), view system folders, etc., and it's way too troublesome to use sudo / enter password in Finder/other applications.

Comment: Well, solving all the problems one runs into by enabling and using the root account daily is troublesome as well (and there seem to be quite a lot of them, from looking at your questions) :-) Honestly I doubt it's worth the effort at the end.

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for your help. I will see if I can switch to an admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly switch between accounts/logins, enable and use Fast User Switching. First login will (of course) take a while as usual, but afterwards switching is very quick. And unless you run big CPU-hogging applications in several accounts at once the additional resource needs are minimal.

Comment: @JoyJin This seems to be a rather specific problem, for most users who need to quickly switch between GUI sessions it works rather fast.